# Wiring question for a multi wire branch circuit

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am moving a bathroom switch that was probably wired in or around 2002 and is on a MWBC - connected to two 20 amp breakers. The source cable is 12/3 and supplies a bathroom exhaust fan, heater and light combination fixture. A nearby receptacle was also connected to this circuit. The fixture (Broan Nu-Tone) requires a 20 amp circuit and says a 15 amp combination switch is adequate. The two cables between the switch and the fixture are 14/3 - one cable controls the heater and the other controls the light and fan. I'm wondering if this wiring is OK or do I need a 12 awg between the switch and the heater element of the fixture. Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum gauge on a 20 amp breaker is 12 gauge, so no 14 gauge wire is allowed(except what is provided on a UL listed device).

That 14 gauge wire is not allowed by code.

The fixtures instructions require a 20 amp circuit, so you cannot change the 20 amp breaker to a 15 amp breaker for the easy fix.  You will be required to change the wires to the right gauge.